# Posting to multiple API's

Tags: php, api

Our current system posts data to multiple API's (all unique). Right now we have individual configuration/format files that we use to translate our data to the data used by the various API's.

Basically it translates it into XML, json, a query string, etc... using the field names and parent/child relationships required by whichever API we are writing to.

The biggest downside to it is that in order to create a new integration (or update and existing one), someone has to physically go into the file and create/edit it, which usually means a developer. Also, while there's only about 20 of these right now, there could potentially end up being over 100.

Is it better to maybe throw these into a DB (whether it's MySQL or a NoSQL)?

One idea I've come up with from a creation/edit stand point is to have our data entry be able to paste in a sample from the API, do a little magic in the background and match up the API field names to our names (and provide a tool to for the user to change it if it's wrong or can't figure out which field matches with which).

Anyone else come across something like this?

Comment: In your third paragraph, you suddenly mention a "configuration", what is that exactly? From the looks, it seems like you could define classes of APIs by their metaformat (XML, JSON, HTTP query) and then use templates for further defining the calls. I wonder whether those are so similar that you can make this generic though...

Comment: I meant integration, not configuration.

Some are similar, there are a few that are basically just flat XML (nodes contained within 1 parent). Overall though, they aren't all that similar.